# Issue with the ShrePoint O365 ribbon

Tags: office-365

Just yesterday all of a sudden my ribbon looks like this:

[image: Closed Ribbon]

I would like to get it back to looking like this:

[image]

Cannot first figure out what changed and how to change it back.  I loaded the page this morning and it showed the whole ribbon for a second and then compressed it to its current state.

Any help would be appreciated.

Michael

Comment: Please, could you provide browser version and browser size????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Zoom settings on your browser. The ribbon changes based on the size of the monitor/browser window, and the browser's Zoom settings. This would explain the ribbon changing to show only groups. The "suite bar" across the top could have changed due to Zoom, a Tenant Admin changing options, or a "SharePoint Online change of the week".

Comment: I checked my zoom, it was at 90%, I changed it to 100% and my ribbon showed back up.  Thank you for your help, you have saved my sanity for this week.